# formatar valor com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
var teste = "006BC953F26DAC56C51D61";
```

e eu gostaria de quando exibir ficasse assim:

```
console.log(teste); //006B-C953F-26DA-C56C5-1D61
```

estou com problemas pois começa com um grupo de 4 careceres e depois 5 e assim por diante.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse plugin: [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). Com ele dá para criar sua própria máscara.

Comment: Parece que a máscara é simples: '0000-00000-0000-00000-0000'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode fazer assim:

```js
var format = function (format, text) {  
  var array = text.split("");
  return format.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, function (index) {
    return array.splice(0, index.replace(/\D/g, "")).join("");
  });
};

var texto = format("{4}-{5}-{4}-{5}-{4}", "006BC953F26DAC56C51D61");
console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Perfeito Tobias

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa, só com uso de `slice` e `join`.

```js
var teste = "006BC953F26DAC56C51D61";

var formato = [
teste.slice(0,4),teste.slice(4,9),teste.slice(9,13),teste.slice(13,18),teste.slice(18)
].join('-');

console.log(formato);
```